# Django custom HTML template not returning any values to the admin.py

Tags: html, django, django-admin

I have created a custom html template with basic checkboxes to select a value and return the value to the Django admin page.

The value of the selected superprofile does not get captured by the variable "selected_value" in the admin.py

The if statement "if request.method == 'POST':" is getting triggered but i keep getting the value of "selected_value" as none

The Html template

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_modify %}
{% block extrahead %}

{{ media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form class="change_superprofile_parent_form" met`your text`hod="POST" class="change_superprofile_parent_form">{% csrf_token %}
        {% for superprofile in superprofiles %}
            <input type="checkbox" name="superprofile_selected" {{ superprofile.checked }} value="{{ superprofile }}"> {{ superprofile }}<br>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Django admin.py

```
    def change_superprofile_parent(self, request, queryset):
        """
        Action to change the superprofile of the selected
        """
        queryset = queryset.values_list("id", flat=True)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            selected_value = request.POST.getlist('superprofile_selected')
        eligible_superprofiles = SuperProfile.objects.filter(status='Active')
    
        return render(
            request, 'admin/auth/user/change_superprofile_parent.html', context={
                'superprofiles': eligible_superprofiles,
            }
        )
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: sorry about that @MahmoudNasser

Comment: @MahmoudNasser the admin.py is simply not detecting any data from the html. I tried 
if 'submit' in request.POST , the submit does not even get detected